# How to prevent 206 HTTP status codes

Tags: joomla, http

I recently upgraded my website from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.0 and I have been getting a crazy amount of traffic through 206 codes than previously with Joomla 1.5. I don't know where to start to go looking for the problem if it even is a problem (if it's just part of the Joomla upgrade) so can someone give some insight to what steps should I take to prevent the amount of bandwidth being used by these HTTP status codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem.    Your server should only respond with `206 Partial Content` if the client requested only part of a document.

This might happen if the request got interrupted the first time for any reason (including the user pressing the stop button in the middle).

This may have started happening all of a sudden because your webserver now supports features that can enable it such as ETags or LastModified.

Comment: So the best thing to do would to contact the host since the amount of bandwidth has 10 folded in the last month?

Comment: 206 partial content responses should be saving you bandwidth since the users are not downloading full pages.  If bandwidth usage has increased, it doesn't seem likely to be related to 206 statuses in your log files.

Comment: 1.1 GB of bandwidth was used with the status so I am quite confused... But either way I will refer it to my host :) Thanks for the input!